# image of adjoint equals orthogonal complement of kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map of finite-dimensional spaces.  Then
$${\rm im}(T^{\textstyle*})=({\rm ker}\,T)^\perp\ .\tag{$*$}$$
I can prove this as follows:
$${\rm ker}(T^{\textstyle*})=({\rm im}\,T)^\perp\tag{$**$}$$
is quite easy, and we know $T^{\textstyle*}{}^{\textstyle*}=T$ and $W^{\perp\perp}=W$, so
$${\rm im}(T^{\textstyle*})=({\rm im}\,T^{\textstyle*})^{\perp\perp}=({\rm ker}\,T^{\textstyle*}{}^{\textstyle*})^\perp=({\rm ker}\,T)^\perp\ .$$
However, I would be interested in a "direct" proof of $(*)$.  It's fairly easy to show ${\rm LHS}\subseteq{\rm RHS}$.  For the converse I have tried obvious things but seem to be going round in circles.

Also, any insights as to why $(**)$ is harder than $(*)$ - if in fact it is :)

**Edit**.  To clarify, I am considering the adjoint defined in terms of an inner product,
$$\langle\,T({\bf v})\mid{\bf w}\,\rangle
  =\langle\,{\bf v}\mid T^{\textstyle*}({\bf w})\,\rangle\ .$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let ${\bf v}\in{\rm im}(T^\ast)$, then ${\bf v}=T^\ast({\bf w})$ for some ${\bf w}\in W$. Now, given ${\bf u}\in\ker T$, we see that $T({\bf u})={\bf 0}$ and therefore
$$\langle {\bf u}\mid{\bf v}\rangle
=\langle {\bf u}\mid T^\ast({\bf w})\rangle
=\langle T({\bf u})\mid {\bf w}\rangle
=\langle {\bf 0}\mid{\bf w}\rangle
=0.$$
That is, ${\bf v}\in(\ker T)^\perp$. Conversely, if ${\bf v}\notin{\rm im}(T^\ast)$, then
*there exists an ${\bf v}'\in{\rm im}(T^\ast)^\perp$ such that $\langle {\bf v}\mid{\bf v}'\rangle\ne 0$.*
In fact, we have ${\bf v}'\in\ker T$ because $T^\ast T({\bf v}')\in{\rm im}(T^\ast)$, which implies
$$\langle T({\bf v}')\mid T({\bf v}')\rangle
=\langle {\bf v}'\mid T^\ast T({\bf v}')\rangle=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
T({\bf v}')={\bf 0}.$$
Therefore ${\bf v}\notin(\ker T)^\perp$, which completes the proof.

Comment: The hardest part is to prove that $(W^{\perp})^{\perp}=W$. For this, it is necessary the Hilbert projection theorem to write every vector as a sum of a vector in $V$ and another in $V^{\perp}$, where $V=W^{\perp}.$ For example, if  $v=v^{\perp}+v^{\perp \perp}$, then $\|v-v^{\perp \perp}\|^2=\|v^{\perp}\|^2= \left\langle v^{\perp}, v-v^{\perp \perp} \right\rangle = 0, $ whenever $v^{\perp} \in W^{\perp}$ and $v^{\perp \perp} \in (W^{\perp})^{\perp}$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm {im}}$
For the inclusion $\im(T^*)\subseteq (\ker T)^\perp$, let $\eta\in \im(T^*)\subseteq V^*$. Then there exists $\xi\in W^*$ such that $\xi\circ T = T^*(\xi) = \eta$. Hence, for every $x\in \ker T$, we have
$$
\eta(x) = \xi\bigl(T(x)\bigr) = 0,
$$
i. e. $\eta\in (\ker T)^\perp$.

Now, you can conclude by noting that $\dim \im(T^*) = \dim(\ker T)^\perp$. Alternatively, you can proceed as follows:

For the inclusion $(\ker T)^\perp\subseteq \im(T^*)$, let $\eta\in (\ker T)^\perp\subseteq V^*$. This means $\eta\colon V\rightarrow K$ is a $K$-linear map such that $\ker T\subseteq \ker \eta$. By the homomorphism theorem, this induces a $K$-linear map $\overline\eta\colon V/\ker T\rightarrow K$, also $T$ induces an isomorphism $\overline T\colon V/\ker T\rightarrow \im T$. This gives us a $K$-linear map
$$
\xi'\colon \im T\xrightarrow{\overline T^{-1}} V/\ker T\xrightarrow{\overline\eta} K
$$
such that $\xi'\circ T = \eta$.
Since we can complete a basis of $\im T$ to a basis of $W$, we find a $K$-linear map $\xi\colon W\rightarrow K$ such that $\xi\big|_{\im T} = \xi'$. Now, it follows that
$$
T^*(\xi) = \xi\circ T = \xi'\circ T = \eta
$$
and hence $\eta\in \im(T^*)$.

The reason why ($**$) is so much easier than ($*$) is that in ($**$) you don't have to construct linear maps. If you want to show $W = W^{\perp\perp}$ without using a dimension argument you would also have to construct linear maps.

---

As a side remark: If you know exact sequences and that taking duals is exact (actually left-exactness suffices, which is a general property of the $\hom$-functor), then you can show $\im(T^*)=(\ker T)^\perp$ as follows: The exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow \ker T\longrightarrow V\xrightarrow T\im T\longrightarrow 0
$$
gives an exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow (\im T)^*\longrightarrow V^*\xrightarrow f (\ker T)^*\longrightarrow 0.
$$
By definition, we have $(\ker T)^\perp = \ker f$ and exactness gives $\ker f = (\im T)^*$ (where we view $(\im T)^*\subseteq V^*$ via the injective map given by precomposing $T$). So it suffices to show $(\im T)^* = \im T^*$. But this follows directly from the definitions.
Here, all the work done above is implicit in the exactness of taking duals.

Comment: I had the first inclusion already - sorry, I should have stated that in the question (it's there now).  For the other, is it really that hard?  I was hoping for something like this: assume ${\bf v}\in({\rm ker}\,T)^\perp$, then identify some specific $\bf w$ such that ${\bf v}=T^{\textstyle*}({\bf w})$.

Comment: Yes, somehow you need to construct your $\mathbf w$ and the homomorphism theorem gives a nice way of doing this. But then again, if you don't want to work that much, you can still revert to a dimension argument.